# python-amazon-product-api installation error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

When installing ***python-amazon-product-api*** using command promt in windows it gives me error:

```
File "setup.py", Line 60
     print 'ERROR: Version %r has not been adjusted yet!' % version_

SyntaxError: invalid syntex
```

Comment: `syntex`? You sure your interpreter is working right?

Comment: Yes i can install other python package with no problem..

Comment: I am using python 3.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no formatting symbol '%' in python3. Change it to:

```
print 'ERROR: Version {0} has not been adjusted yet!'.format(version_)
```

Comment: So can't i use **python-amazon-product-api** with **python 3.3.2** because there may be more formatting symbol "%" in code ?

Comment: python-amazon-product-api is for python 2.x, you can try to fix source code to support python 3.x. There are automatic converters like http://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html but I never tried it.

Answer (score 2):

What you stumbled accross is one of my safe-guards to prevent uploading a wrong version number to PyPI. But those should not be a problem if you use `python setup.py install`.

As for support for Python 3: It is forthcoming. I just need to find the time to do it ;)